# if statement executing even if condition is false

Tags: java, spring, loops, if-statement

I am trying: if `abb.iscurrentlyy()` returns true, then go inside the `if` statement or `abb.islately()` is true.

What is wrong with my if statement? When I set `abb.iscurrentlyy()` to be false. `abb.islately()` is set to true. Why is `abb.iscurrentlyy()` going inside the loop even `abb.iscurrentlyy()` is false?

```
    if (abb.iscurrentlyy() || abb.islately()) {

        if (reqFiles != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < reqFiles.length; i++) {

                Future<ExecResult> lcukv = executor.submit(worker);
                executionFutureException.add(lcukv);
            }
        }

    } else { // do if condition is false.
    }
```

Comment: Your saying if one of these is true, execute the loop if the `reqFiles != null`. Else if both `abb.iscurrentlyy()||abb.islately()`conditions are false

Comment: When posting here please indent your code properly so we can read it. This time only I did it for you. Next time your IDE can do it for you. Or really: my IDE did it this time.

Comment: Thank Ole! i will take care of it next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term `or` (||) means that for the conditional to be true at least one of the sub-conditions has to be true.

```
boolean condition1 = true;
boolean condition2 = false;

if(condition1 || condition2)
{
    System.out.println("One or both conditions were true");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Both conditions were false");
}
```

In real world terms, imagine walking into an ice cream shop. You like strawberry ice cream. You also like chocolate ice cream. You hate all other flavors. If the shop has at least one of those flavors, you're happy.

Your code is analogous to the example above. If, on the other hand, you want false when one of the conditions is true and the other is false, use `and` (&&).

```
boolean condition1 = true;
boolean condition2 = false;

if(condition1 && condition2)
{
    System.out.println("Both conditions were true");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("At least one condition was false");
}
```

In this case, the ice cream shop has to have both flavors you like in order for you to be happy.

Think of `or` as being more permissive: "I can have this OR that to be true." `and`, however, sounds inclusive, but it's actually more exclusive: "I have to have this AND that to be true."

Comment: Excellent explanation and thank you! my scenario is something like this if statement is inside a for loop. 1st loop checks condition1 is true and go inside. and then in 2nd loop that is to check if condition2 is true or false? is there a way to check only condition2 in 2nd loop and avoid checking condition1?

Comment: @Sam Try not to change the question after it has been answered because the answers then no longer match what you were asking and people who stumble on this question later won't understand what's going on. Most people who use this site never post questions because they find what they want in existing answers, so we encourage people to leave the original question as is. You should revert your latest edit and post a follow up question separately. I'll be sure to take a look.

Comment: My bad. good point. i am new to stack-overflow. still learning.  i just reverted back the change.

Answer (score 2):

In your code both `abb.isCurrentlyy()` and `abb.islately()` needs to be false to not go inside loop. `||` works as a logical OR. which means if either one of the value is true statement is evaluated as True. I suggest you to write individual if loop for these two condition.